# Find the real and imaginary part of $z = \frac{e^{\pi i + 1}}{2-i}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find the real and imaginary part of $$z = \frac{e^{\pi i + 1}}{2-i}$$

We probably have to use Eulers identity ($e^{\pi i} = -1$).

My attempt: $$z= \frac{e^{\pi i + 1}}{2-i} = \frac{-e}{2+i} = \frac{(2+i)(-e)}{4-(i^2)} = \frac{-2e-ei}{5}$$

$$\Rightarrow \Re(z) = \frac{-2e}{5}, \Im(z) = \frac{-ei}{5}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Nearly correct.. You have an additional $i$ in $\Im z$.

Comment: Seems correct except that on the second equality you wrote $2+i$ instead of $2-i$. Though, you didn't continue that mistake. Also the imaginary part is just $\frac{-e}{5}$

Comment: I agree with @sharding4, in my opinion although I would simplify by multiplying by the conjugate of $2-i$ *first*, and then simplify $e^{\pi i +1}$, although these operations are commutative (so you can do them in the reverse order compared to mine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we get $$\frac{-e}{2-i}=\frac{-e(2+i)}{4+1}=-\frac{2e}{5}-\frac{e}{5}i$$